# How to PROPERLY secure your home access router?

Tags: security, router, login

I have a Debian server with a dyndns hostname and a open 22 port on my router (DLINK DSL-2640B) because i need to remote-ssh my server. The Debian machine itself is extremely secure but some hackers were able to hack into my router , in fact firstly i saw some weird open ports that I did not open , but i thought my colleague opened it so i did not really care about it. Next day i was not able to log in to my router..someone changed the password. My question is...**is there a way to enable a maximum number of log-ins in order to prevent brute-force attacks?** Interesting thing ..i had captcha enabled..how did they log in??

Comment: What router do you have? Remember to include _all_ the relevant details in your question. If we have to ask for them, you're likely to get downvoted or have your question closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also a good idea to be on the lookout for security breaches/problems with your router, for example this one http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/18511/. Most routers had some problems in the past, like the recent WPS problems on the Speedport W912V.

Comment: Oh my god unbelievable!! Thanks alot for the website!

Comment: Hopefully d-link releases a new fw..this bug is pretty bad...

Comment: Don't count on it. [The product is listed as end of life](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/support/product/dsl-2640b-adsl-2-wireless-g-router-with-4-port-10-100-switch) and has never had a firmware update of any kind.

Comment: @Aaron: Now you just need to figure out which one of your LAN side colleagues is screwing you over.

Comment: Don't forget to secure your Wi-Fi connection; that's part of your LAN from the router's perspective and the exploit could be done through Wi-Fi as well.